# Make "Table" appear in List of Tables - How to align Table and number of table in the same length

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, numbering, vertical-alignment, texmaker

I want the word "Table" to appear in my list of table and thus I use "\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }" in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % to define source command

\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{rotating} % to use sidewayrotate
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{diagbox} % to draw a diagonal in a cell in table \backslashbox
\usepackage{tocloft} % for list of table and list of figure
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table } 
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
%\listoftodos
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{XXXXX}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
\caption{International Standard Classification of School Categories and Uni's Aggregate Categories}\centering\small\
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLLL }
\hline
    2017 & Aggregate Categories of School & 2008 & 1988 & 2010 \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{sidewaystable}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics on ABC on XYXZ database}\centering\label{tab:bit}
\begin{tabulary}{1.2\textwidth}{LLR} 
\hline
    Time span &  & 1962-2017 \\ \hline  
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\chapter{YYY}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
\caption{International Standardfgdfg Classification of School Categories and Uni's Aggregate Categories}\centering\small\
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLLL }
\hline
    2017 & Aggregate Categories of School & 2008 & 1988 & 2010 \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{sidewaystable}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Descriptive jhfhg on ABC on XYXZ database}\centering\label{tab:bit}
\begin{tabulary}{1.2\textwidth}{LLR} 
\hline
    Time span &  & 1962-2017 \\ \hline  
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Data Source fro X y Z and A B C D stuff combined here - just an example of long table name}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLL}
\hline
    Variables & Proxies &           Unit &           Source \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
```

However, in the list of Tables, The length of "Table + no. of table" are adjusted to the justify format and they does not look vertically aligned in the list. Please have a look at the picture.
    Could you please help me how to fix this? - To vertically align "Table + no. of table"

[image]

Comment: Sorry this is my first time on the site.I added the code that can produce the error that "Table + no.of table" are not vertically aligned in the List of TAbles. Thank you.